# Planning an amplifier using a transistor

Tags: transistors, amplifier

I want to <s>plan</s> design an amplifier of <s>tension</s> voltage using a transistor:
[image]

but I don't know how I can choose the values of \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$, \$R_3\$, \$R_4\$, \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$..

I want to obtain a gain of 3, and I want \$Z_{in}=15k\Omega\$ and \$Z_{out}=3k\Omega\$. Could you help me? I've just started to study this subject.

Comment: Looks like homework! What have you tried?

Comment: What frequency?

Comment: Gain of 3 - is that into a load?

Comment: @LeonHeller R4=Z_out=3k ohm, R3=R4/3=1k ohm, R2=\$\beta R3=10^5\$ ohm (beta is the gain in DC).. now I have to find R1.. but what about C1 and C2?

Comment: What frequency?

Comment: @LeonHeller I haven't any restriction about it

Comment: It is required for C1 and C2!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Output impedance is specified by you as 3kΩ, this sets R4.
- The ratio R4/R3 defines your gain in this circuit, which you specified as 3. You can calculate R3 now.
- The parallel circuit \$R_1//R_2 = \dfrac{R_1×R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$ is specified by you as 15kΩ. The transistor's base will load the voltage divider, but this is easily less then 10% when the transistor's gain is 100 or more. You can neglect it.
- All you need to decide on is the bias voltage at the base of the transistor. Start half way the supply voltage and see how it works. If you realize yourself that the voltage across R4 is three times higer than the voltage across R3, then you can calculate the optimum DC voltage for the base (which is 0.7V higher than the voltage on R3) for largest swing.

But this method of guesstimating is probably not what your teacher is looking for.

Comment: I'm so grateful for you kindness.. There is a thing that I don't understand: is \$Z_{in}\$ equal to \$R_1//R_2// \beta R_3 \$ or not?

Comment: and, this is the last question, what about C1 and C2? aren't their values important? thanks again

Comment: These things are a bit rusty for my, but I believe my teacher expected us to write: R1//R2//(β+1)R3 Not that β+1 will make much of a difference in small signal transistor circuits.

Comment: The capacitors depend on the frequency you want to use. \$X_C = \frac{1}{\omega C}\$ should be about a factor 10 lower than \$Z_{in}\$ and you can neglect it again. Regular components are accurate up to 5%, hence all the neglecting going on, but you *must* be aware of that you are neglecting things and always consider if it is correct.